# How to decide/action make a Wiki?

Tags: discussion

Is this a good question to make a Wiki out of?

[Is there a serious alternative to the Raspberry Pi that includes Gigabit Ethernet?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14356/is-there-a-serious-alternative-to-the-raspberry-pi-that-includes-gigabit-etherne)

And what is the process to flag this up?